# Value not getting properly initialized with the right value based on ternary condition

Tags: angular

I have the following method implemented in Angular7 . I am getting this.FundDetails.FundStrategyId as undefined even when this.ManagerStrategyId has value. While debugging I can see this.SelectedFundStrategyId is undefined.  Is there any issues with my condition. I am expecting 
this.FundDetails.FundStrategyId to contain value when this.SelectedFundStrategyId is undefined and this.ManagerStrategyId has value

```
this.FundDetails.FundStrategyId = typeof this.SelectedFundStrategyId  === 'undefined'  || !this.SelectedFundStrategyId
                                                ?  this.ManagerStrategyId : this.SelectedFundStrategyId ;
```

Code

```
 saveFund() {
        if (!this.FundDetails.FundName || this.FundDetails.FundName === '') {
            this.notify.error('Fund name is mandatory.'); 
            return;
        }

        this.FundDetails.FundStrategyId = typeof this.SelectedFundStrategyId  === 'undefined'  || !this.SelectedFundStrategyId
                                                ?  this.ManagerStrategyId : this.SelectedFundStrategyId ;
        if (this.SelectedFundId === 0) {
            // Need to pass the manager_strategy_id as well
            // Need to pass FirmId to get filter flagship funds

            this.fundService.createFund(this.FundDetails).then((result) => {
                if (result) {
                    this.getFundDetails(this.SelectedFundId);
                    this.notify.success('Fund Details Successfully Created');
                    this.EditMode = !this.EditMode;
                    this.managerFundDetailsEvent.next('getManagerStrategyFunds');
                    this.dismissEvent.next('dismissFundPopup');
                }
            }).catch(err => {
                this.notify.error(err.InnerMessage);
            });

        }

  }
```

Comment: Are you sure that `ManagerStrategyId` as a value by the time that your condition is executed? Sorry to have second thoughts but you should `console.log` the value of `ManagerStrategyId` right before your condition to be sure. Otherwise your condition looks good to me, yet could be improved as @bryan60 as pointed out in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57147957/11755228).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can simplify your condition like this:

```
this.FundDetails.FundStrategyId = this.SelectedFundStrategyId || this.ManagerStrategyId;
```

hard to tell if this will fix the problem since I can't tell if either of the variables actually would have a value from the provided code